# unable to generate .deb file using make deb-pkg?

Tags: apt, kernel, deb

I am trying to build my linux source tree. I used following steps :

```
sudo make clean
sudo make localmodconfig
sudo make menuconfig 
sudo make deb-pkg
```

But after completion I was not able to see any .deb package generated. I checked the parent directory also, but no luck.

EDIT: Actually I checked the build log and it is happening because of the following error

```
/home/rahul/linuxcode/linux/scripts/package/builddeb: line 65: dpkg-gencontrol: command not found
make[1]: *** [deb-pkg] Error 127
make: *** [deb-pkg] Error 2
```

But I am not able to find the reason, I installed the dpkg-control package also, but the error persists.

Comment: it would be useful if you could explain what you have and what you are trying to do with that (besides create a .deb, obviously).

Comment: @Seth I have downloaded a kernel using git. Now I want to build it and install it. For building .deb I used above steps, but no luck generating .deb.

Comment: Hm, want to explain what this kernel looks like, where you downloaded it from and why you want to make it a deb?

Comment: Here is the link https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/

Comment: btw, it's best to *edit* this information into your question :)

Comment: Did you install the dpkg-dev package ?

Comment: yes it was the problem. After installing this package, everything was working fine :)

Comment: You should raise a bug about this, it makes no sense whatsoever not to check this first before spending 30 minutes compiling!

Answer (score 1):

From OPs comments

> After installing the `dpkg-dev` package, everything was working fine
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
> ```

Comment: Raise a bug about this issue!